# Hooking the new line number mode in Emacs 26.1 doesn't work

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

In my `init.el` file, I am using a hook to display line numbers in all programming modes:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)
```

When I recently upgraded to Emacs version 26.1, I wanted to take advantage of the new `display-line-number-mode`, minor mode since it is supposed to be

> much faster and doesn't usurp the display margin for the line numbers

according to the NEWS file. So I simply replaced `linum-mode` in `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-number-mode)
```

however, it doesn't work, when Emacs loads I get the message:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: display-line-number-mode
```

Hints on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function is `display-line-numbers-mode`, not `display-line-number-mode`. Simple spelling mistake.